# CMOS AND Circuit calculate power consumption

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, cmos, power-consumption

I need to calculate the power consumption of the CMOS AND circuit and I tried to figure it out myself but I really don't have a clue. I don't need the full answer but a first step into the right direction would be really helpful!
We are using the OrCAD software.

Thx a lot <3[image: cmos and]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is CMOS-type logic, most of the time only one of the p/n mosfet pairs is conducting which means (pretty much, ignoring leakage currents) no current is flowing.

The most power is therefore lost in the switching phase, when the mosfets switch roles (MOSFET1: conducting -> nonconducting; MOSFET2: nonconducting -> conducting).
In the following I will neglect the losses from both mosfets conducting at the same time when changing roles.
 Since you need to change the gate-source voltage of the mosfet to change the current flowing through it and the gate has a certain capacitance, you need a certain amount of charge to accomplish this change of gate voltage and therefore, current. This means that you will need a certain amount of energy for each switching cycle (E = Q_gate * abs(U_start - U_stop) = 0.5 * C_gate * (U_start - U_stop)^2 where the absolute value for  (U_start - U_stop) will be 4.9V or 5V in your case).

So basically you need to figure out how many transistors get switched at what frequency to get the average power consumption (P = dE/dt = (n * 0.5 * C_gate * U^2) / T =  n * 0.5 * C_gate * U^2 * f where f is your switching frequency, n the amount of mosfets switched, U your supply = 4.9V/5V).

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is stupid, I needed to change subjects on a really short notice and I'm really bad with electrical engineering... So you basically only count the V1 input when talking about U=4,9V as I understood it, but V2 has an Input of 4,8V and V3 has a constant supply of 5V? Maybe that isn't needed in the overall power consumption but it really confuses me a lot. But I already have a basic issue of understanding the circuit since as I learned it the three PMOS at the top will never conduct any current since they always lock because of the supply :(

Comment: I think it would be a great idea for you to review n and p type mosfets and their switching characteristics. P type mosfets start conducting when the gate-source voltage reaches -V_threshold, so the p channel mosfets will switch too. I would make a table of all possible input transitions and what all the mosfets do what for that transition. That will be some work but not that difficult. Btw: Greetings from the Uni of Stuttgart, im an ETIT student too :D

Comment: I think I tried this before... How do I know the threshold value for the p mosfets ^^"? And are they the same for all p/n or are they different? I was looking at the waveform for the circuit as well and its like, completely confusing... The whole assignment builds on calculation the power consumption for different supply voltages and thresholds as well as the output rise and fall times. As it stands now I really only understand train station but I think once I fully understood it its really not that difficult ;-; Grüße von der BTU Cottbus zurück :D

Comment: Well, you can get the threshold voltage from the datasheets of the mosfets. But if you need to take the actual fall and rise times of the input signals into account, I am afraid this calculation is quite complicated and quite far out the scope of such an online forum. Why? Because that probably means you will have to take into account the phase where both mosfets are conducting (you need to look at the linear and saturation regions of the characteristic curves), which is a topic that took my professor 3 hours of lecture to explore.

Comment: I don't think I am supposed to take the rise and fall times into account for the power consumption, we are just asked to determine those times, as I understood from the hints for the assignment I can simply do that with the waveforms of the OrCAD, but the power consumption is really beyond me. But I still don't quite get how the three locking p elements are supposed to act, like, they will always just lock won't they O.o?

Comment: The threshold voltage of the BS250 is -3.5V, which means U7 or U8 will conduct when V1 or V2 is below 5V - 3.5V = 1.5V. Since U7 and U8 are connected in parallel, a current will now flow into gate of U6 charging it up and allowing a current to flow through U6, which will then pull the output low.

Comment: I think you explained it really well but I don't really catch a single thing of what you're saying. I feel like I lack a basic understanding of circuits with thresholds, P/NMOS and all that stuff. All I ever learned was P blocks current when 1 and N passes current when 1 and vice versa for 0 but this obviously doesn't seem to be the case ... It's frightening of how little explanation there is only for CMOS circuits that go more in detail with all that stuff ;-; Also I didn't find a single CMOS AND tutorial, its all NAND or OR or sth like that T-T

Comment: Sorry, whats your educational background? The task you are asking about is a typical exercise for electrical engineering students in 4. Semester and it doesnt seem like you have been given the knowledge to be able to complete such a task. Basically your asking me to explain 2 years worth of studying to you since you dont seem to be able to do simple circuit analysis.

Comment: I‘m a computer science student in my second master semester, I had two basic ET courses back in my bachelor covering a little bit of CMOS. Since you’re required to have a least 12CP of technical computer science for the master I am required to solve some ET tasks one way or another :/ The other courses that are offered aren’t really less complex… The course doesn’t have any „must have knowledge“, it only recommends the knowledge of the two courses I heard and passed (with very good grades at that)

Comment: So you are able to do simple circuit analysis (KCL, KVL, "maschenstromanalyse", "knotenpotenzialanalyse")? Then I would really recommend to invest some time into understanding mosfets. This video seems like it could be helpful to you, its about CMOS Inverters but also about n/p-channel MOSFETs (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBu-efEact8)

Comment: Tyvm, I watched like 4h of content from that guy and I feel like I have a MUCH better general understanding now :)! I reached out to my assistant professor to ask my questions and it turns out we aren't supposed to calculate the power consumption ourselves but rather we are supposed to read it from the OrCAD software, big wow. Thx so much anyways! Grüße nach Stuttgart :D